# How to make checkbox checked with JQuery 1.3.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery version is **1.3.2**

There is a checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="flag_concept" name="flag_concept" value="1" />
```

On document load I want it to be checked :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    {/literal}
    { if $oConcept->flag_encours == 1}
    {literal}
    $('#flag_concept').attr('checked','checked');
    {/literal}
    {/if}
    {literal}
});
```

But it doesnt work !

Comment: Have you tried `$("#flag_concept")[0].checked = true;`

Comment: If using `attr('checked','checked');` doesn't work in your case then some other part of your code is wrong. I'd suggest removing the `if` condition and verifying that it works (it should), and then working out what's wrong with the `if`. I'm unfamiliar with the syntax you're using, so I'm unable to be more help, although I don't see where `$oConcept` is defined.

Comment: it is a Jelix syntax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *pure javascript* instead of jquery if no problem to do it without jquery:

```js
document.getElementById("flag_concept").checked = true;
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="flag_concept" name="flag_concept" value="1" />
```

because all suggestions and answers not working for you, i suggest using `.trigger()` like this :

```js
$( "#flag_concept" ).trigger( "click" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="flag_concept" name="flag_concept" value="1" />
```

Comment: yeah , trigger("click") did it !

Comment: That's good ! always we can move around problem and find many ways to solve it, _Thanks. !_

Answer (score 0):

You can try ;

```
$('#encours_concept').attr('checked', true);
```

And Here is a snippet;

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <html>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#chkTest").attr("checked", true);
        });
      </script>
      <body>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" />
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Not sure about your answer but what is wrong with `.attr('checked','checked');` ?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but I tried 'checked' a few months ago. That is not working. But 'checked', true works for me.

Comment: Make sure that you are giving the true id, and you're not doing another things wrong. Because the snippet works.

Answer (score 0):

You have given wrong id in jquery:

Try by applyinh .prop:

```
$('#flag_concept').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: `$.prop()` was added in jQuery 1.6. The question specifically asks about an older version.

Comment: major issue is id was wrong. otherwise  $('#flag_concept').attr('checked','checked');  is working jquery 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use checked property since you need it on page loadright..

```
<input type="checkbox" id="flag_concept" name="flag_concept" value="1" checked/>
```

Comment: the problem is that when I uncheck it then I always get it when posting the form !

Comment: why cant you upgrade your jquery version.. try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery

Comment: i already tried to use recent version but there are lots of old code in the project ; it is an oldd project that we are doing maintenance !